# Application of first Borel Cantelli lemma

Tags: real-analysis

Q) Let $(X,\mu)$ be a positive measure space. Suppose $f,f_1,f_2,\cdots$ are functions in $L^1(X,\mu)$ such that $\sum_n \int_X |f_n - f|d\mu < \infty$. Show that $f_n$ converges $\mu$-a.e. to $f$.

My attempt: Let $E_n = \{x\in X: f_n(x)\not\to f(x)\}$. If $\mu(\limsup E_n)=0$, then $f_n\to f$ a.e. but I am not sure how to use my definition of $E_n$ and the information given in question: $\sum_n \int_X |f_n - f|d\mu < \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mu \{x \in X: |f_n-f| >\epsilon\}$$ $$ \leq \frac1  {\epsilon}  \int_{\{x \in X: |f_n-f| >\epsilon\}} |f_n-f|d\mu$$ $$ \leq \frac1  {\epsilon}  \int |f_n-f|d\mu$$ Now sum over $n$ and use Borel Cantelli Lemma. You see that almost surely for any $\epsilon >0$, $|f_n-f|\leq \epsilon$ for $n$ suffcienltly large.

Comment: Why the downvote? Since the title explicitly mentions B-C Lemla I thought OP was supposed to use it. I was aware of the alternative proof where you show that $\sum|f_n-f| <\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Or: Monotone convergence shows that $$\int\sum |f_n-f|=\sum\int|f_n-f|<\infty.$$ Hence $\sum|f_n-f|<\infty$ almost everywhere, so $f_n\to f$ a.e.

Comment: The title indicates that OP wants a  proof using first B-C Lemma.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Or it could be just an XY thing, where he wants any solution but B-C was all he could think of. (No, I didn't downvote your answer...)